# Is there a way to force a ios web app to use VPN connection?

Tags: html, ios, vpn

Is there a way to force a ios web app to use a VPN connection?

Comment: prefs:root=General&path=Network in Safari takes you to the VPN tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of iOS 5.0.1, no.  The closest solution I have come up with is to point to the VPN tab to make sure VPN is on...